# Python To Javascript - Numpy Issue

Tags: javascript, python, numpy

I have this piece of code that i am trying to convert from Python to Javascript. It is a non-maximum suppression function. It seeks to remove maximum values around a local maximum in a 2D array of floating point values. Since it is using a numpy function, it does not convert easily to javascript.

```
 def non_max_suppression(plain, window_size=3, threshold=NMS_Threshold):
        under_threshold_indices = plain < threshold
        plain[under_threshold_indices] = 0
        return plain * (plain == maximum_filter(plain, footprint=np.ones((window_size, window_size))))
```

Here is an approximate conversion, still in Python. However, the result is not the same. It provides approximately the same result but some of the maximums are suppressed that should be kept.

```
def non_max_suppression(plain, window_size=3, threshold=NMS_Threshold):
        under_threshold_indices = plain < threshold
        plain[under_threshold_indices] = 0
        outter = np.zeros((46, 54))
        for i in range(window_size, 41, window_size):
            for j in range(window_size, 49, window_size):
                maxVal = 0;
                maxLoc = [-1,-1]
                for k in range(i-window_size, i+window_size):
                    for h in range(j-window_size, j+window_size):
                        if(plain[k][h]>maxVal):
                            maxVal = plain[k][h]
                            maxLoc = [k,h]
                if(maxVal>0):                            
                    outter[maxLoc[0]][maxLoc[1]]=maxVal
        return outter
```

This is easy to convert to Javascript.

```
function makeArray(w, h, val) {
    var arr = [];
    for(i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for(j = 0; j < h; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = val;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

non_max_suppression(plain, window_size=3, threshold=this.NMS_Threshold) {
        var nmsImage = makeArray(plain.length, plain[0].length,0);
        for(var i=0; i<(plain.length); i+=1){
            for(var j=0; j<(plain[i].length); j+=1){
                if(plain[i][j]<threshold) {
                    plain[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        for(var i=window_size; i<(plain.length-window_size); i+=window_size){
            for(var j=window_size; j<(plain[i].length-window_size); j+=window_size){
                var maxVal = 0;
                var maxLoc = [-1,-1];
                for(var k=i-3; k<i+3; k+=1){
                    for(var h=j-3; h<j+3; h+=1){
                        if((plain[k][h]>maxVal) && (plain[k][h]>=threshold)){ 
                            maxVal = plain[k][h];
                            maxLoc = [k,h];
                        }
                        //plain[k][h]=0;
                    }
                }
                if(maxVal>0) {
                    nmsImage[maxLoc[0]][maxLoc[1]] = maxVal;
                }
            }
        }
        return nmsImage;
    }
```

Any advice on how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think the problem is, that you didn't look for the maximum in one dimension as it is stated in the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/11509c4a98edded6c59423ac44ca1b7f28fba1fd/scipy/ndimage/filters.py#L988) of scipy.ndimage.maximum_filter:

```
"""Calculate a one-dimensional maximum filter along the given axis.
```

You need to rerun the maximum search along the y, x and the diagonal axis seperatly: [wikipedia non-max-suppression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Non-maximum_suppression)

Comment: Awesome stuff. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.... no pun intended.